# Replace Data Query

Tags: ms-access

I created a fairly simply Access database. I am going to be using this with an inventory database. Boxes all have numbers that will include an asterix before and after each number. For example, 101 will read *101* in order for the scanner to read it. Is there a way to write a query that will delete every asterix in all of the records?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Update Query using the VBA Replace Function should work fine

```
UPDATE [TableName] SET [FieldName] = Replace([FieldName],"*","")
```

**References**

- [Create and run an update query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-run-an-update-query-9dddc97c-f17d-43f4-a729-35e5ee1e0514)
- [Replace Function](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Replace-Function-6acf209b-01b7-4078-b4b8-e0a4ef67d181)